# Passing a dynamically allocated matrix to be modified in a function in C

Tags: c, matrix, allocation

Okey, so I need to dynamically allocate a matrix in C and then pass it to be modified in a function (I want the changes that I make inside the function to remain after I return to main). This is what i did:

```
void read_zone (int *(**m), int N, int M) {
    int x, i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            scanf("%d", &x);
            m[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
```

And then inside main() I have:

```
int **m;
int N = 2, M = 3;

m = (int **) malloc(N * sizeof(int *));

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    m[i] = (int *) malloc(M * sizeof(int));
}
read_zone(&m, N, M);
```

So the problem is that when it enters the function it seems that m[0][2] is not allocated (even though m[0][0] and m[0][1] are), but in main I can access it, so it's definitely caused by the way I pass it to the function (&m).
What's the right way to do it?

Comment: struct zone vs int ? what? and why passing the address of `m`? you're not changing it in your read_zone routine.

Comment: what do you mean, "it seems that"?  I don't see anything in your code that shows that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to dereference it first like this because then you get the double pointer to which you have allocated the memory dynamically

```
(*m)[i][j] = x;
```

Also don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

In fact passing the address of `m` here is *redundant* in the very first place. You can simply do this

```
read_zone(m, N, M);
```

And

```
void read_zone (int **m, int N, int M) {
   ..
       scanf("%d", &x);
       m[i][j] = x;
   ..
}
```

The thing is here passing the address of the variable won't serve you any purpose. You are not changing the value of the double pointer.

If you have compiled your code - you will see that compiler complained about type mismatch. Function signature would be

```
void read_zone (int ***m, int N, int M) (The way you did)
```

Check the return value of `malloc` , `scanf` to know whether if the call to them were successful or not.

Free the dynamically allocated memory when you are done working with it.

Compile code with all flags enabled `gcc -Wall -Werror progname.c`.(Using `gcc`).

Comment: why passing the address of `m` in the first place?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre.: Yes. True.

Comment: and `m` has type `int **` in the caller and becomes `struct zone **` in the callee. Suspect.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it worked. Thanks a lot!
@Jean-FrançoisFabre.: I modified my code to make it easier to explain what the problem is and isolate it, forgot to change that, sorry